# Calibre tries to open PDFs (but not DJVUs) with epub viewer

Tags: ubuntu, calibre

It leads to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/utils/ipc/simple_worker.py", line 284, in main
    res = {'result':func(*args, **kwargs)}
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/oeb/iterator/book.py", line 55, in extract_book
    plumber = Plumber(pathtoebook, tdir, log, view_kepub=view_kepub)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/conversion/plumber.py", line 720, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Input file must have an extension')
ValueError: Input file must have an extension
```

Comment: How are you opening them?

Comment: @music2myear I tried both double clicking on them and clicking on them and then clicking "PDF" in the sidebar, neither worked.

Comment: Please add this info to the question itself, using the EDIT button, to make your question more clear.